# c# reliable MouseMove (hop)

Tags: c#, mousemove

I'm using this function to move the cursor.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
```

When I use a hotkey to trigger it, the cursor will move to the correct coords and next time I move the mouse it continues from that position. Working as intended.

However I need to trigger SetCursorPos during a MouseMove event. If user moves mouse into a certain area I want it to hop to a different place and carry on from there. But right now it hops to the destination and then immediately hops back (90% of the time). How can I avoid that behavior?

Edit: I decided to work around it by clipping the cursor in 1 by 1 px square for 1 mousemove event. Cursor.Clip(MousePosition, new Rectangle(1, 1));

Comment: Please post your MouseMove event handler code.

Comment: I'm literally just calling that function and nothing else in MouseMove event.

Comment: @user1340531: Post it anyway?

Comment: This tends to suffer from the "what if *two* programs did this?" dilemma.  Like you and the program that gets the mouse move messages.  The user always loses.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there is another control on top of your form in the area where you want to trigger the event. If so, the control is capturing the `MouseMove` event.

For example, here I've added a green 200x200 panel at position 0, 0 in the upper left hand corner. If the mouse moves over the panel, the form's `MouseMove` event will stop capturing the mouse cursor position. In my form's `mouse_move` event, I set the form's text to display the mouse coordinates. Notice the coordinates in the Window Text are still 200, 200 when the mouse was actually at 0, 0 (can't see my cursor due to having to click on SnippingTool.exe to get the screenshot).

[image]

To remedy this, use the same code you placed in your form's `MouseMove` event in the panel's `MouseMove` event (or whichever control you are using). This results in the correct coordinates in the form's text.

[image]

And here is the code (This could obviously be refactored into a single method):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = string.Format("X: {0}, Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);

        if (e.X >= 0 && e.X <= 200)
        {
            if (e.Y >= 0 && e.Y <= 200)
            {
                SetCursorPos(500, 500);
            }
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = string.Format("X: {0}, Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);

        if (e.X >= 0 && e.X <= 200)
        {
            if (e.Y >= 0 && e.Y <= 200)
            {
                SetCursorPos(500, 500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My MouseMove event is actually global, it's triggered no matter what I'm hovering, as long as the cursor moves.

Comment: @user1340531 As the other commenters stated, you need to add that code to your question.

Comment: Mainly because there's no such thing as a "global" MouseMove event, unless you've installed a global hook.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say with such little Information (maybe a screenshot of your GUI would help).
You could try:

```
    private void Button_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SetCursorPos(0, 0);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```